# How do I let user pick date for time object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, datepicker, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't know why this is so difficult and I'm sure there's an easy answer, but i've been looking for about an hour and cannot find it.  I have a form where I want someone to enter a time into a text field in the form hh:mm:ss .   What I have now is:

```
<%= f.text_field :complete_time %>
```

:complete_time is an attribute of data type 'time'.  So if someone enters '15:53:00', the :complete_time is stored as:

```
 2000-01-01 15:53:00 UTC
```

I can't figure out how to let the user set the date of the time.  Above the time field, I also have a datepicker field, but it is mapped to its own attribute.  I would use the date picker in conjunction with the time text field if i knew how, but I don't.  How do I let the user pick the date of the time object?

Comment: Which column type is your complete_time in your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is this plugin you can use in with date picker to pick the time, it's really easy to use. http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker